# Why can't I use "Find" in a password read-only Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, read-only

After some testing, it appears that if you use the "[password to modify](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/password-protect-documents-workbooks-and-presentations-HA010148333.aspx)" feature on a Word document, and you opt to open it as read-only, it disables almost every feature, including things like "Find", which doesn't seem to change the document at all. But it manages to preserve "Go To" from the same tool window.

But if you just set a file to read-only, it lets you do anything but save to that file. Since both files are being opened as read-only, why is there such a difference between the two situations?

Comment: Just a guess, it prevents you from using the Replace function on the Find dialog.

Comment: @KevinPanko I was thinking the same thing, but you can use the "Go To" tab, and not the "Find" tab.

Comment: It's pretty strange.